# How can invoke SOAP webservice in node js with NTLM authentication

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, ntlm

I'm a newbie in NodeJS, and I need some help to connect to a SOAP Webservice which is on NTLM authentication.

When executing this code, an error appears in httpntlm module:

```js
C:\soapclient\node_modules\httpntlm\ntlm.js:106

callback(new Error("Couldn't find NTLM in the message type2 comming from the server"));
                ^
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Object.parseType2Message 
(C:\soapclient\node_modules\httpntlm\ntlm.js:106:3)
    at sendType3Message 
(C:\soapclient\node_modules\httpntlm\httpntlm.js:66:23)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\soapclient\node_modules\httpntlm\httpntlm.js:93:4)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

and the code :

```js
var soap = require('soap-ntlm-2');
var url ='https://ws.tmb.cat/secure/ws-ibus/IBusService?WSDL'

var options = {
wsdl_options: {
    ntlm: true,
    username: "xxxxxx",
    password: "xxxxxx"

}
};

soap.createClient(url, options, function (err, client, body) {
 
if (err) {
    console.log("4")
    console.log(err);
}    
client.setSecurity(new soap.NtlmSecurity(options.wsdl_options));
 
console.log(client.describe());
report = client.getAllArrivaltimes({}, function(err, res){
           console.log('err='+err);
           console.log('res='+res);
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in http-ntlm module.
It does not pass the `callback`, so it's `undefined` when it is called.

Here is the related bug on GitHub:
https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm/issues/48

And here is the fix for this problem:
https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm/pull/51